# Convert ZIP command from windows to unix

Tags: unix, zip

I am trying to recreate a zip command from windows in Unix and facing issues as expected. 
Windows command is

`zip "zipfilename.zip" -j -u -m -g -T -9  "sourcefiledirectory\*20181010.*`

On UNIX the pattern `*20181010.*` is not getting identified and i am getting the message 
    `"zip warning: name not matched".` 
Please help in getting over this.

Comment: Can you share the command that you are firing on Unix?

Comment: Try to use -y along with the command

Comment: I was able to execute the command on the command line in unix but was getting issues while trying to replicate the same through an ETL tool 'BODS'. The issue was fixed when i put the command into a .sh executable and called that executable from BODS and passing the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified the wildcard path in Windows format (i.e. using "\" for the path separator, rather than "/")

```
"sourcefiledirectory\*20181010.*"
```

try this instead

```
"sourcefiledirectory/*20181010.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute the command on the command line in unix but was getting issues while trying to replicate the same through an ETL tool 'BODS'. The issue was fixed when i put the command into a .sh executable and called that executable from BODS by passing the zipfile name and source file pattern as parameters.